# Pan Events issue with ionic WKWebView for iOS 13.2

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ios13.2

In my ionic-cordova application, I have drag and drop functionality where I use
**pan events** to drag and drop and use this:

```
document.elementfrompoint(x,y)
```

returns **empty object on latest iOS 13.2**. After analyzing the the latest upgrade was only the WKWebView engine for iOS.
When I downgraded and fall back to UIWebView by:

```
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
```

Observed that it **returned a complete element object**.

And in both the cases I tried passing same x and y co-ordinates.Still it is returning a empty object.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if your pan events are getting triggered? In my application, I was facing this issue when pan events were not getting triggered on iOS 13 and when I tried to call document.elementfrompoint(x,y), was returning null.

For me, this was happening because pointer events are supported by iOS 13 and Hammer can not handle it properly. In this case, Hammer takes default input type as pointer events. I solved it by disabling pointer events support in Hammer. I disabled it only for iOS.

```
import { HammerGestureConfig } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

export class HammerConfiguration extends HammerGestureConfig {

   buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
    if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/) ) {
      return new Hammer(element, {
        inputClass: Hammer.TouchMouseInput
      });
    } else {
      return new Hammer(element);
    }
}
```

You can also refer to https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1084
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19594